# Windows Phone Button binded to a Item specific method

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have a listbox binded to a list of Item , each Item Template has a button. The button should execute a item's method when i tap to it, for example a Delete method that remove the item from the observable collection binded to the listbox, is it possible? Should i give a better explanation of what i think?

Comment: You should not repeat button for certain action in listbox item template. Action button should be in application bar & listbox should have selection mode enable.

Comment: You can use **context menu** from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if action will affect entire list (add, delete item) you should go with selecting item and deleting it from app bar. But if it affects only one item - in my opinion you can place trigger in the this item (example share item text, add to fouvorites). You can achieve that by using Command pattern and MVVM. I often use MVVM Light and its RelayCommands. XAML implementation looks like follows:

```
                    <Image Source="Images\appbar.share.png"  Width="60" Height="60">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShareItem}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Image>
```

And ViewModel side (for this item) should contain implementation for this Command. Please look at this article [MVVM Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)